# Why is this recursive function not processing the entire list?

Tags: python, recursion

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code I am writing? I am trying to find a sum of all elements in this list. My code:

```py
def determine_sum(m_list, sum_count): 

    for i in range(len(m_list)): 

        if isinstance(m_list[i], int):      
            sum_count += m_list[i]  


        else:  
            return determine_sum(m_list[i], sum_count)

    return sum_count 

m_list = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], [4, [3,4]] ]

print(determine_sum(m_list, 0))
```

The output is `15`, but I expected `26`.

Comment: Tip: a `for ... in range():` loop where the numbers are only used to index some object should be simplified to `for ... in ...:`.

Answer (score 2):

```py
def determine_sum(m_list, sum_count): 

    for i in range(len(m_list)): 

        if isinstance(m_list[i], int):      
            sum_count += m_list[i]  

        else:
            # Don't return here, just add the count and keep looping
            sum_count = determine_sum(m_list[i], sum_count)

    return sum_count
```

Comment: This returns the number 78, which is not a sum of the elements in the list.

Comment: Fixed it, needed =, not +=

Answer (score 1):

Getting the sum of the sample list: 26

You were missing to add the output of the nested determine_sum in the sum_count.

```py
def determine_sum(m_list, sum_count): 

    for i in range(len(m_list)): 
        if isinstance(m_list[i], int):      
            print(m_list[i])
            sum_count += m_list[i]  
        else:  
            sum_count = determine_sum(m_list[i], sum_count)
    return sum_count 

m_list = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], [4, [3,4]] ]

print("Sum:", determine_sum(m_list, 0)) # 26
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your code is this line:

```
return determine_sum(m_list[i], sum_count)
```

If you run into another list, you call `determine_sum` recursively, which computes the sum of the sub-list and starts with a count of `sum_count`. However, whatever the result is for the first sub-list, is the total result you're returning. Your function ignores any following lists, because `return` ends the function.

A recursive function like this doesn't need to pass `sum_count` around. Instead, you can just compute the sum of a sub-list recursively and then *add* the result to the current sum, continuing the loop. Every call of `determine_sum` will get its own copy of the running sum, so you don't need to pass it.

Like this:

```
def determine_sum(m_list): 
    sum_count = 0

    for i in range(len(m_list)): 
        if isinstance(m_list[i], int):      
            sum_count += m_list[i]  
        else:  
            sum_count += determine_sum(m_list[i])

    return sum_count 

m_list = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], [4, [3,4]] ]

print(determine_sum(m_list))
```

So, you weren't far off.

Note: some of the other suggested solutions keep the parameter `sum_count` and change the problematic line to:

```
            sum_count = determine_sum(m_list[i], sum_count)
```

That also works, but is only recommended if you're writing a function that's intended to *add* the recursive sum of lists to some existing number. Given the name of your function, it doesn't seem like that's really your aim.

Comment: Glad to hear it @SebastienBoulas - you should probably accept the answer that helped you the most as the answer to your question, so that it is no longer marked as unanswered.